# Getting all divs under mouseover with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, position, mouseover

I got stuck when i was tring to mouseover a div that is inside another div.
I have something like this in the code:

```
<div id="container">

<div id="content">
// I have some stuff and other divs inside here
</div>

<div id="background">
// this div is on the back of the website and will animate some stuff on mouseover
</div>

</div>
```

When I try to capture the mouseover on the div "background" to animate it using jquery, I aways get as a result the top div "container".

I found this exemple in another post : http://jsfiddle.net/MPTTp/
I'm using it to debug the div that is under the current mouse position.

Is there a way to capture this mouseover of the "background" div even if there is something on top of it?

Comment: In newer browsers you can set [`pointer-events=none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to overlaying elements. If you want to use `elementFromPoint()`, you can put it in a `mousemove` handler of the topmost element. Then set `display:none` for the returned element untill it's the wanted one, or `body`. Hidden elements need to be cached, so you can return them to the view from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method that you need to use `document.elementFromPoint(x,y)`

Take a look at [this sample](http://jsbin.com/IDAzoYi/2/edit?html,js,console,output) that I had done, for more detailed information:

```
document.addEventListener("mouseover",function(e){
  console.log(document.elementFromPoint(e.x,e.y).id);
 });
```